# Ubuntu 14.04 FTP server

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

I am using ubuntu 14.04 server and installed FTP server on it. If ftpuser login via any FTP client, he/she can see all the stuff on the server instead of his/her own folder.This user should have only WWW folder access. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!! just comment out this line in the vsftpd.conf file

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```